# Hibernate OneToMany without a foreign key

Tags: hibernate

Is there any way to tell JPA to not create a Foreign Key on a OneToMany relationship when creating tables? Here is some sample code of what I'm trying to do:

I have two entities called Project and Group. Each project can contain many blogs and each group can contain many blogs. There is, however, only one blog table that stores all blogs. The Blog table has a column called containerId which holds the ID of the parent container. For example, if a blog belongs to a group with ID 100, the containerId column for blog holds the value 100.

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="containerId")
@Where(clause="containertype=600")
public Set<BlogEntity> getBlogs() {
    return blogs;
}
```

When I try to insert a blog into the blog table with a valid Group ID, I get a hibernate error saying "Integrity constraint violation - no parent FK84B5A4F0388ED18F table: PROJECT in statement". It looks like both Project and Group tried to create a foreign key on the same column (containerId) in the blog table. How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're not forced to create your tables with Hibernate. You might use a custom SQL script.

Now, having such a database design is not very clean, because you can't enforce any foreign key constraint for the container_id column.

I would either use two columns (group_id and project_id) in the blog table, or use two join tables (group_blogs and project_blogs). This would make Hibernate happy, and would improve the database.

If you worry that this design might allow a blog to belong to a group and a project, then use a check constraint on the blog table ensuring that group_id or project_id is null. Harder to do with two join tables, though.

That said, if you really want to keep that design, I think the key is to use the [`@Any`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-any) annotation to map the inverse relationship (from Blog to Group/Project).

Answer (score 0):

Having one column, ContainerID in the Blag table is a bad approach in my opinion. You would be better off creating two different tables for joining the Blog table to the two different tables. You could have a BlogProject table and a BlogGroup table. Each would have a BlogID and ProjectID or GroupID, respectively. These tables would be your indicator as to where the blogs map to. This is the same kind of approach you would use in a ManyToMany relationship.